# Error when connecting to kubernetes in CLIPPER.AI

Tags: python, kubernetes, minikube, google-kubernetes-engine

We are creating a POC with CLIPPER. The deployment works fine with Docker in local environment, but we need to use kubernetes for the POC. We tried to deploy it in two ways:

1. Minikube deployment
2. GKE k8 cluster deployment

In both above cases: the `mgmt-frontend`, `redis`, and `query-frontend` images were all deployed successfully on the cluster:

[image]

We are getting an error when we are trying to start clipper:

```
Error connecting to Kubernetes cluster. No external node addresses found
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4de1563b3f9a> in <module>()
      9 clipper_conn = ClipperConnection(KubernetesContainerManager('35.188.55.76'))
     10 
---> 11 clipper_conn.start_clipper()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/clipper_admin/clipper_admin.pyc in start_clipper(self, query_frontend_image, mgmt_frontend_image, cache_size)
    112             self.connected = True
    113         except ClipperException as e:
--> 114             logger.warning("Error starting Clipper: {}".format(e.msg))
    115             raise e
    116 

AttributeError: 'ClipperException' object has no attribute 'msg'
```

We tried different options but it didn't help. Can anyone please help us on this?

Comment: Hey, are you able to resolve this error?

Comment: Yes.Refresh your gcloud creds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did refresh on the gcloud creds after updating the cli to the latest version